# MySQL - Select rows in time range grouped date and id

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I'm having trouble with a query I need to get some data from my db.

I have a table with the following data:

```
id    user_id     game_id    date
1     1           1          2015-08-19
2     1           2          2015-08-19
3     1           3          2015-08-19
4     2           1          2015-08-20
5     2           2          2015-08-20
6     1           1          2015-08-20
7     1           1          2015-08-20
8     3           1          2015-08-20
9     2           1          2015-08-21
10    1           1          2015-08-21
11    1           2          2015-08-21
12    2           1          2015-08-21
```

I need to get the total amount of users that "played" on a date range, i.e 2015-08-10 to 2015-08-22, grouped by date and user_id.
For example, with this data given the result should be:

```
total_players    date
1                2015-08-19
3                2015-08-20
2                2015-08-21
```

I've tried this the following query but it doesn't group correctly:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS total_players 
FROM plays 
WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
GROUP BY date, user_id
```

Can anybody help me with the correct query?
Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: remove `user_id` from `GROUP`

Comment: I've tried that but I need to count any repetition for the same user_id in one day as one. For example the rows 1,2 and 3 should be counted as one because the user_id is the same for that day. If I don't group by user_id I get more results than I should.

Comment: no, if you don't group by `user_id` you will get LESS result records

Comment: `SELECT date, count (distinct user_Id)` ...`group by date` (assuming date is JUST date and not datetime)  otherwise you have to format date to be just a date in both select and group by.

Comment: It's datetime but it's nothing it can't be solved with DATE_FORMAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM plays
WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
GROUP BY date
```

Tested locally on test database with your data

```
total_players    date
1                2015-08-19
3                2015-08-20
2                2015-08-21
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08957/3

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS total_players 
FROM plays 
GROUP BY `date`
```

or

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS total_players 
FROM plays 
WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
GROUP BY `date`
```

Comment: Yes this is correct but Xeridea answerd first. Thank you very much anyways!